# linking multiple table confusion

Tags: sql, join

I have the following tables. Each header has a status and many boxes underneath. Each box contains multiple lines and for each specific line multiple other lines. Here's my query:

```
select 
    Header.all, 
    count(no of available boxes), 
    count(number of available received lines), 
    sum(line_table.qty), 
    sum(receivedline_table.qty) 

where 
    HeaderNo like %something%
```

`Header_Table`:

```
[HeaderID]  [HeaderNo]  [Ref]   [StatusID]
-----------------
1   ||HNO1  ||Ref1  ||1
2   ||HNO2  ||Ref2  ||2
```

`Header_status_Table`:

```
[HeaderStatusID]    [statusDesc]
-----------------
1   ||Desc1
2   ||Desc2
3   ||Desc3
```

`Box_table`:

```
[BoxID] [HeaderID]  [BoxNo]
-----------------
1   ||1 ||BNo1
2   ||1 ||BNo2
3   ||2 ||BNo3
```

`Line_table`:

```
[LineID]    [BoxID] [QTY]   [HeaderID]
-----------------
1   ||1 ||15    ||1

2   ||1 ||2 ||1
```

`ReceivedLine_Table`:

```
[RecievedID]    [LineID]    [qty]
-----------------
1   ||1 ||5
2   ||1 ||10
```

I have written the following scripts, but unfortunately it's not working as I expect.

```
SELECT H.ID, H.No, H.Ref1, H.Ref2, H.Ref3, HS.StatusDesc, sum(isnull(LR.ReceivedQty,0)) as ReceivedQTY, sum(isnull(L.OrderedQty,0)) as OrderedQTY, count(L.Lineid) as NoLines , count(B.BoxID) as NoBoxes
        FROM Header H 
        left outer JOIN HeaderStatus HS ON H.StatusID = HS.StatusID
        left join Box B on B.ID = H.ID
        left join Line L on L.BoxID = B.BoxID
        left join LineReceived LR on L.Lineid = LR.LineID
        where H.No like '%%'
        group by H.ID, H.No, HS.StatusDesc, H.Ref1, H.Ref2, H.Ref3
```

Comment: "Not working like I expect" is not a good error description; _how_ is it failing you?  Also, could we please get your desired results, given your sample data?  Although I have a feeling this is likely a common 'duplicated row' issue...

Comment: I want to select a header.* with a specific status + number of boxes in header + number of received lines + sum of received QTYs + sum of Line QTYs

Comment: words inside [ ] are columns' names and whatever underneath the ------- are data seprated by ||

Comment: ...Not what I meant.  You say it's failing - is it not returning the right record?  Is one of the values off?  Is it throwing a syntax error?  Most of us could tell what your starting data was; given that, construct a new "table" that comprises your desired results. (In general, tab-separated data is fine - `||` might be taken as data, especially as you have _two_ of them, or, depending on the DBMS, viewed as a `CONCAT` operator.)  Also, in case we need DB-specific functionality, please list what 'flavor' you're using (MySQL, DB2, SQL Server, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it, I just select separately inside my select script, the data are not rubbished and seems well
HS.statusdesc as status,
                        (select count(B.ASNBoxID) from ASNBox B where B.ASNID = H.ASNID)as NumberOfBoxes